# FontForge Modified guillemets do not work in Microsoft Word

Tags: fonts, microsoft-word

I have adapted the guillemets in the free Google Libre Baskerville font for visual dialogue, and I can type and print fine from all native Mac applications such as Textedit, but the font doesn't appear or paste into a Word document. The instructions suggest that adding fonts to Microsoft Word for Mac is just a matter of adding them to your system with the Fontbook. This is not the case.

A metric view of the extended font is below. The saved .WOFF loads fine into my machine, and I can use it fine.

What must be done to allow Microsoft access to a new font on a Mac?

[image: Metrics view glyphs]

Here is the repertoire of the font showing my properly encoded glyphs in Fontbook.

[image]

Comment: I found [something here](https://office-watch.com/2022/using-woff-fonts-in-microsoft-office/#:~:text=WOFF%20are%20a%20new-ish%20type%20of%20font%20that,and%20mobile%20apps%2C%20not%20desktop%20programs%20like%20Office.) which suggests MS Office can't use WOFF fonts.  Also this isn't really a graphic design question, and MS Office isn't a graphic design application.  This question might be better suited to [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: Thank you, I suppose I have to output a different format. Many graphic design houses accept or even expect final publications in Microsoft Word today, believe it or not; or Microsoft Publisher as well. However, what I need to achieve is a font designed which is compatible with printing and editing via the presentation medium. I believe those are topics better suited here as superusers likely don't design custom fonts with FontForge.

Comment: I think you have to restart Word in order to rebuild the font cache, but that doesn't seem to be the issue here. From your pictures, it looks like Word is displaying the characters from two rows above the highlighted character in your second image. Perhaps this is a smart quotes issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WOFF fonts were [always intended](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Open_Font_Format) to be incompatible with most desktop apps like Microsoft Word. The font industry was worried that once websites started to serve custom web fonts they would be easily pirated.

Fortunately, Libre Baskerville is an open-source font so you have the right to modify it. FontForge will do export in ttf or otf format which Microsoft Office can read. Or you could [download it in ttf format](https://github.com/impallari/Libre-Baskerville) from the GitHub page of its lead designer Pablo Impallari in ttf format and copy your modifications over to that.